# pd.to_datetime inconsistent with time.mktime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

```
import time
import pandas as pd
x=pd.to_datetime('2017/01/01',yearfirst=True)
print('x:', x)
y=pd.to_datetime(time.mktime(x.timetuple()),unit='s')
print('y:', y)
```

The result is:

```
x: 2017-01-01 00:00:00
y: 2016-12-31 16:00:00
```

I'd expect them to be the same, since we usually transform TimpStamp to seconds and then transform them back. 
I understand that this has things to do with timezone, but how can I eliminate the timezone effect?

Edit: 
Package information: Python 3.6, Pandas 0.23.1 and dateutil 2.7.3
Local timezone： UTC+8

Comment: What versions of Python, Pandas, and dateutil do you have? Because when I run this exact code, either on my local machine with 3.7 (which is in Pacific Time), or [on repl.it with 3.6](https://repl.it/repls/ParallelTremendousNotifications) or [with 2.7](https://repl.it/repls/ImmediateMeekCarrier), all with recent versions of the libraries, I always get `y: 2017-01-01 00:00:00`.

Comment: Python is 3.6, Pandas 0.23.1 and dateutil is 2.7.3, but my local timezone is UTC+8.

Comment: My local timezone is also UTC+8. My Pandas and dateutil are older than yours, but the ones installed on repl.it are newer than yours, so that can't be it. So, I'm stumped.

Comment: But meanwhile, why do you _need_ this to work? The main reason people do the whole shuffle between datetime, struct_tm, and float this way is for legacy code written for Python 2.x or 3.2 and/or really old Pandas versions, back when both modules were missing key methods. Nowadays, both Pandas and `datetime` can go directly to and from timestamps without needing `struct_tm`, or the `time` module at all (and also without the performance costs and lost precision, although those probably don't matter to you here).

Comment: I'm UTC-5 (New York) and I get `y: 2017-01-01 05:00:00`.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the comments, I actually just found out that TimeStamp has a ".value" attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that the problem is because time.mktime assumes that the timetuple is a local time. Since I am at UTC+8, time.mktime would first -8 hours to convert it to UTC, then convert it to seconds.

Thanks to @abarnert, I found that we can just use x.value (it's nano seconds), and if we need the seconds version, just have x.value/10**9.

In addition, in case anyone want a time zone neutral version, there is calendar.timegm(x.timetuple()) that does a similar job with time.mktime() but is timezone neutral.